# Jenkins gradlew build failed to download support-v4

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, support-v4

On CentOS, I installed a Jenkins and try to build android on it, I run ./gradlew build in the project folder and it's ok, but when I build with jenkins, it prompt:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':PagerSlidingTabStripLib:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0.
     Required by:
         adt-android:PagerSlidingTabStripLib:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.0/support-v4-23.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.0/support-v4-23.1.0.pom'.
               > Connection to https://jitpack.io refused
      > Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.0/support-v4-23.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.0/support-v4-23.1.0.pom'.
```

The support jars exists under my android sdk folder: **android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/**
but gradlew can't find it. And the log shows that the maven center does not has the **support** folder.

I have update the support library and support repositories by :
android update sdk --no-ui
But it does not works.

This local.properties:

## DO NOT check this file into source control.

sdk.dir=/home/jenkins/android-sdk/

============================================

## **SLOVED**

---

The reason is the jenkins account don't have the read permission for extras/ folder, where the support lib resides. Just **chown jenkins extras** worked.

The origin permission looks like:

```
drwxr-x---  5 mysql 4096 12月 22 12:59 extras
```

Just chown to jenkins and chmod to 775:

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 jenkins 4096 12月 22 12:59 extras
```

Comment: support libs are not yet stored in maven repository but under sdk folder. You sync to them via your sdk manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your environment variable to include Android SDK path

1. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System
2. Check "Environment variables"
3. Add name: ANDROID_HOME, value -> your android sdk dir path
4. Click "add"
5. Click save

Also you might also want to check permission of read on the android sdk folder.

Comment: gradlew has found the sdk

Comment: i dont get it , in your question you have mentioned "but gradlew can't find it."... what em i missing here ? or did this solve your problem.

Comment: I mean gradlew cannot find the support-v4 jars under the SDK， then it try to download a non-exist URL.

Comment: post your local.properties file. If you checked that into jenkins then gradlew is probably using a different path to android sdk. It should be something that resides in the same server where you have deployed your jenkins CI tool.

Comment: Maybe there're some hidden sdk. I've updated the local.properties above.

Comment: Well in that case you need to verify where exactly is your android sdk, as all support libs reside in that. Also I think you should create a local.properties file in your repo to include the path of the android sdk which jenkins has access to. You might also want to check permission of read on the android sdk folder.

Comment: You saved my day, it is the problem of **extra/** folder permissions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome.please accept as answer if it solved your problem.Thank you